# Google Fonts does not render on mobile devices when using TailwindCSS

Tags: html, firebase, tailwind-css, vercel

I'm using TailwindCSS to create a portfolio website. Not using anything fancy, just a static website using Tailwind.

Recently, my font that is "Inter" from Google Fonts is not rendering on mobile browsers. It was working before suddenly stopped worked when I extended a few colors.

The weird thing is, everything works fine on desktop browsers with mobile screen sizes using dev tools in Chrome and Safari.

Does anyone know what seems to be the problem or experienced the same issue?

Thanks in advance!

**Here is my code:**

**My src css file:**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**My tailwind.config.js file:**

```
module.exports = {
  purge: {
    mode:'layers',
    content:['./public/**/*.html/']
  },
  darkMode: 'media', // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    
    extend: {

      fontFamily: {
        'body': ['Inter'],
      },

      colors: {
        cwc: {
          red:'#FF0000',
        },

        black: {
          900:'#000000',
          800:'#0D0D0D',
          700:'#191919',
          600:'#333333',
        },

        bg: {
          white:'#F6F9FC',
        },

        text: {
          primary:'#0b0014',
          paragraph:'#61656b',
          secondary:'#61656b',
          tertiary:'#90959D',
          highlight:'#1f66ff',
        },

        button: {
          neutral:'#676B71',
          hover: '#0b0014',
        },

      },

    },

  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**My postcss.config.js file**

```
const cssnano = require(cssnano);
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
    cssnano({
      preset:'default',
    }),
  ]
}
```

Comment: have you added the font per this guide? https://daily-dev-tips.com/posts/using-google-fonts-in-a-tailwind-project/

Answer (score 0):

**Setup Google Fonts**

First of all, head over to `Google Fonts` and find a cool font you want to use.

Open up the font and click the "Select this style" button for each style you like.

*Select Google Font styles*

With it selected, you'll get a sidebar on the right showing the `<link>` attribute for it. Copy this link method.

Now head back to your project and open the `index.html` file. We'll place this import above our styles.css file.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- other stuff -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
</html>
```

**Add to Tailwind**

Now let's extend our Tailwind theme to have it know about this font.

Open the `tailwind.config.js` file and extend the theme's fontFamily option.

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        'press-start': ['"Press Start 2P"', 'cursive']
      }
    }
  }
};
```

If your font like this example uses spaces, it's best to use the double escape `'""'` it will make sure it's used in the right way.

Our font will now be available as font-press-start we can add this to our heading on the homepage like this:

```js
<h1 class="text-6xl font-press-start">Welcome</h1>
```

Comment: So why does it work for the OP on desktop but not in mobile with his current code?

Comment: He most likely had it cached